# HTML/CSS - Why does my page have a small empty area around it?

Tags: html, css

Here I have a very simple webpage. One div, basically. But this div has an area of nothing around it despite my width being set to 100%. Here's a picture demonstrating.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
<html>
    </head>

        <link href='mainStyle.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

        <script src='jquery.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='navTop'></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And my mainStyle.css:

```
#navTop{
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
}
```

This is probably just a dumb CSS mistake. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The page `body` has margins applied to it by the browser - it's called the user agent stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Browsers give the `<body>` 8px of margin by default

Answer (score 3):

Browsers have default margin/padding on various elements, including `html` and `body`. You'll need to set them to zero as well if you want your `div` to go right to the edges.

Comment: Different browsers all behave differently, so IMO it's better to cover all possible situations. It's certainly not going to hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you're `<body>` needs to have it's margins and padding set to 0.

**CSS:**
`body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser has default styling (font-size, font-familly, line-height, etc. including margin and padding around the document).

To avoid extra space around the document, you may add in your CSS :

```
body,div,p { margin:0;padding:0; }
```

so these elements won't keep default values.

Another, fancy method, is to use a [CSS reset script](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to ensure that almost all default stylings are overwritten to be 0/null so there is only your own rules that count.